# How to open the display settings in command line?

Tags: command-line, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, gnome-control-center

I have Ubuntu 18.04 installed and when I  have set up an additional monitor for my laptop which, for obvious reasons, is used as a primary monitor.

However, sometimes when I start the laptop the additional monitor stays blank and I have to either restart or restart `gdm3` in order to have it working.

I have found that if I make a slight change in the `Displays` settings the second monitor wakes up. The problem is that it's quite hard to open that application when the main (additional) monitor is blank.

Is there a way to open `Settings` or `Display settings` from command line?

Just to make sure I've expressed myself clear enough this is the application I want to open:

[image: Display settings]

PS: I've added `nvidia` tag because the GPU is Nvidia.

Comment: I tried to find the same thing, my conclusion was that gnome settings is a module of gnome-shell & can't be run directly (from terminal) so I hope you get a better answer  (outside of `dconf-editor`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command would be:

```
gnome-control-center display
```

You can use tab completion with `gnome-control-center` to see a list of available panels:

```
$ gnome-control-center 
background        keyboard          printers          ubuntu
bluetooth         mouse             privacy           universal-access
color             network           region            user-accounts
datetime          notifications     removable-media   --verbose
default-apps      online-accounts   search            --version
display           --overview        sharing           wacom
info-overview     power             sound             wifi
```